# Update Query with JPA issue

Tags: jpa

I have this **function**:

```
public void updateAnimal(int idToModify, String name, String type, int age) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "UPDATE PetHospital.Animal SET animalName=:name, animalType=:type, animalAge=:age WHERE idAnimal=:idToModify");
    query.setParameter("name", name);
    query.setParameter("type", type);
    query.setParameter("age", age);
    query.setParameter("idToModify", idToModify);
    query.executeUpdate();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

And I get this **errors**:

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:  Exception
> >     Description: Syntax error parsing [UPDATE PetHospital.Animal SET
> >     animalName=:name, animalType=:type, animalAge=:age WHERE
> >     idAnimal=:idToModify].  [30, 40] A path expression must start with an
> >     identification variable. [50, 60] A path expression must start with an
> >     identification variable. [70, 79] A path expression must start with an
> >     identification variable.
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1605)
> >         at util.DatabaseUtil.updateAnimal(DatabaseUtil.java:84)
> >         at main.Main.main(Main.java:32) Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
> >     2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException Exception
> >     Description: Syntax error parsing [UPDATE PetHospital.Animal SET
> >     animalName=:name, animalType=:type, animalAge=:age WHERE
> >     idAnimal=:idToModify].  [30, 40] A path expression must start with an
> >     identification variable. [50, 60] A path expression must start with an
> >     identification variable. [70, 79] A path expression must start with an
> >     identification variable.
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
> >         at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
> >         ... 2 more

I want when I call that function in main with that parameters to update `SQL` line with new values get by parameters.

Comment: Maybe `UPDATE PetHospital SET PetHospital.Animal animalName=:name`

Comment: @K.Nicholas PetHospital is the schema and Animal the table. Now I get: Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':name, animalType=:type, animalAge=:age WHERE idAnimal=:idToModify' at line 1
Error Code: 1064. I think it's something related to parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The error "A path expression must start with an identification variable. " describes a problem with the "path". The path is the dot notation that identifies a field. See, e.g., [Paths and Types in JPQL and Criteria API](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/path).

So, you probably need to say

```
UPDATE PetHospital.Animal a SET a.animalName=:name, a.animalType=:type, a.animalAge=:age WHERE a.idAnimal=:idToModify
```

Comment: Yeap, now I get: [76, 87] The state field cannot be resolved.
[101, 111] The state field path 'a.idAnimal' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

Comment: You will need to update your question to include the Entity so we can verify the names of your fields.